# How to set connection type in AWS Java SDK? - HTTPS vs HTTP

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I am downloading gigabytes of data (a large number of small files) at a time and would like to optimize the download times by instead using a `HTTP` request instead of using `HTTPS`, which is a slower process, especially if repeated thousands of times before each transfer.

What is the default request protocol for the Java AWS SDK and how can I set it to `HTTP`?

Comment: FYI, default for the AWS Java SDK is HTTPS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When constructing a client object (For example `AmazonEC2Client`), you can pass in an optional `com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration` object to customize the client's configuration.

Use the below constuctor:

```
AmazonEC2Client(AWSCredentials awsCredentials, ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)
```

Read more [here](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3604).

Now, while creating the `ClientConfiguration` object you can use `setProtocol()` to define the protocol to be HTTP or HTTPS. And accordingly the client object hence created would use that protocol. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/ClientConfiguration.html#setProtocol(com.amazonaws.Protocol)).

Comment: Thanks this was exactly what I was looking for.